# Add Unique Key For Nullable Columns - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using sql server 2008 R2 and would like to apply unique key constraint to nullable columns. This code works good, but if I have multiple columns to add this rule to, it would generate as many 'nullbuster' columns.

```
ALTER TABLE tblBranch
ADD nullbuster AS (CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN BranchID ELSE NULL END);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_Column1 ON tblBranch(column1,nullbuster);
```

Is there any way that I could achieve the goal without generating new columns.

### EDIT:

Followed @marc_s suggestion, here to create an unique key constraint.
The target column is BranchCode. Now, there is one record in the table that has NULL for BranchCode. When I try to insert a new record, with Null BranchCode, from c#, it gives an error saying - Cannot insert duplicate key for unique index UK_BranchCode.
But, when I manually insert a record in the database, it does accept null values. 
Where am I going wrong.

CS

```
Guid gId = Guid.NewGuid();
cmd = new sqlcommand("insert into tblBranch(BranchId,BranchCode) 
                      values(@BranchId,@BranchCode)",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId",gId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode",txtBranchCode.Text);//empty text here
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Close();
```

Comment: Well, the **empty text** is ***NOT*** the same as `NULL` !! If you want to actually store a `NULL`, use `DBNull.Value` (instead of `string.Empty`)

Comment: I tried cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode",txtBranchCode.Text.Length > 0 ? txtBranchCode.Text : DBNull.Value.ToString();....It says, Cant insert duplicate key row...

Comment: Just use `DBNull.Value` - no `.ToString()` ! Maybe you'll need to do the check outside the `.AddWithValue()` call

Comment: Declared a string sName, Outside Addwithvalue. When I say sName=DBNull.Value, it says cannot implicitly convert null to string. When I add , ToString(), it errors out at ExecuteNonQuery :(

Comment: See my updated response - you should **NOT** assign `DBNull.Value` to a temporary string, of course - see my code snippet, use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're creating a `nullbuster` column for each nullable column you want to index? Seems like overkill....

Wouldn't it be **much easier** to just create **filtered indexes** for those nullable columns, something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_Column1 ON tblBranch(column1) WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL;
```

and thus allow any number of `NULL` entries, while uniquely indexing the other values. That way, you don't need to add all those `nullbuster` columns just to make indexing possible...

Read more about filtered indexes:

- [Create Filtered Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) (on Technet)
- [Introduction to Filtered Index – Improve performance with Filtered Index](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/)

**Update:** in order to set a parameter to **NULL** (and not an empty string), use this code:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBranchCode.Text))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchCode", txtBranchCode.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I try to insert values manually in the database table, it accepts multiple null values for that column and also the Unique key constraint works good.
But, I'm unable to insert a second null value for the target column through a c# program.

It says SQLException. Cannot insert Duplicate values.

Comment: @Ruby that is not a problem with the index then. Find the bug in your app.

Comment: I am unable to find out and updated my question. Someone please help me out

Comment: THANK YOU MARC. That worked. Could you plz tell me how it would be using objects. The same way didnt work here. tblBranch objBranch = new tblBranch; objBranch.BranchCode = DBNull.value //cant implicity convert....

Comment: @Ruby: you can use the `DBNull.Value` **only** when you're dealing with ADO.NET stuff - like calling a stored procedure or something like that. Otherwise in your regular .NET code, just use `Null` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use the filtered index suggestion provided by marc_s. You say that you are still getting a unique index violation. What does that tell you? It tells you you are inserting a duplicate key with regards to the index definition. You think, you aren't, but you definitely are.

How to debug that? You look at what you are inserting. You look at `gId` and `txtBranchCode.Text` in the debugger. Also, you look at the error message, because it says:

> The duplicate key value is ...

All of these clues lead you to find that `txtBranchCode.Text` is not null, but an empty string. Insert `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move column1 to a new table and make it unique and non-nullable. Reference the Branch table using a foreign key in the new table. Populate the new table only where you have a (non-null) value for column1.

Creating a new table is the surest way to support any dependencies on column1. A column that permits nulls is not a *key* column but column1 apparently should be. Putting that column into a new table also happens to be the only way to satisfy Normal Form and that ought to be the default approach unless you have a very compelling reason to "denormalise" column1 into the Branch table where it doesn't seem to belong.